# issue generating json file from AttributesToJSON in Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

```
I have a scenario where list of files are coming from previous processor, where for each file, I have to create json file with attributes of the flowfile. In AttributesToJSON processor configuration there is option to extract pipeline attributes and can create json files/object, if we set Include Core Attributes to true, it will read some of the file properties and forms the json file
```

```
the out for the above case in my scenario is …
{"fragment.size":"125"
file.group:"root",
file.lastModifiedTime:"2020-12-22T15:09:13+0000",
fragment.identifier:"ee5770ea-8406-400a-a2fd-2362bd706fe0",
fragment.index:"1",
file.creationTime:"2020-12-22T15:09:13+0000",
file.lastAccessTime:"2020-12-22T17:34:22+0000",
segment.original.filename:"Sample-Spreadsheet-10000-rows.csv",
file.owner:"root",
fragment.count:"2",
file.permissions:"rw-r--r--",
text.line.count:"1"}
}
```

But the files has other properties, like absolute.path, filename, uuid  are missing in the above json file.
My requirement is, get the absolute.path, filename and uuid and concatenate absolute.path+/+filename, assign this to custom attribute say filepath:absolute.path+/+filename and also add uuid to json object.
so my json file should like

```
{ uuid:"file uuid value", filepath:"absolute.path+/+filename" }

 

any inputs to get above  form of json file
```

Comment: include core attributes into json with `Include Core Attributes` parameter. probably specify with `Attributes Regular Expression` attributes to include into result...

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for [AttributesToJSON](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.AttributesToJSON/) you can see that you can specificy attributes in the `Attributes List` property. So you could try listing the properties you want there.

Alternatively. Sounds like you have 1 FlowFile for each File? You could use [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) to insert fields. You can use the `Literal Value` for the `Replacement Value Strategy` which will let you use [Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) to insert values - for example, you could add a Property called `filename` with value `${filename}` to insert the value of the `filename` attribute to a field in the JSON called `filename`.

To concat the two fields you could do `${allAttributes("absolute.path", "filename"):join('/')}` or use `append()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I solved this by using custom attributes in updateRecord, then I extracted these custom attributes from AttributesToJSON , this has solved my problem.